# IP Address List of URL

Tags: objective-c, firewall, ipfw

In my application , i need to block URL i have done something like that, 
I believe, i need to execute ipfw rule through Cocoa using NSTask to do so i have integrated 
[STPrivilegedTask](http://sveinbjorn.org/STPrivilegedTask)
But problem i am supplying rule ipfw add 12164 deny tcp from any to www.facebook.com
and return with the rule

```
12161 deny tcp from any to 66.220.149.11
```

But still i am able to access www.facebook.com and now its coming from some different ip address,

So i believe, i need to have list of all URL associated with the domain name, is it feasible to get in Program ?

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way of doing that as of now is,

on terminal : type host [url]
i will get ip address associated with that URL,
to have it programmatically, i am making use of NSTask and configured output to a file,

Once again thanks for looking at it.